# How to make text scroll horizontally on a button script with 2 variables?

Tags: javascript, html, button, scroll

Our company was provided this code snippet of a button to put on our website to connect to our virtual booth. I would like both sets of text to scroll horizontally across the page (left to right), depending on the booth status. Can someone please help me? This is the code:

```html
<script src="https://www.websitehere"></script>
<div class="btn-booth-container" 
style="cursor: pointer; 
color: #F7F6F2; 
background-color: #507C8F;
padding: 10px;
text-align: center;
font-weight: bold;"

onclick="openIframe('https://www.websitehere/booth/XXXX//?embed=true')" 
data-boothid="XXXX" 

data-boothon="CLICK HERE TO CHAT WITH US IN OUR VIRTUAL BOOTH" 

data-boothoff="SCHEDULE A VIRTUAL MEETING" 

id="div_booth_status"></div>
<script>updateBoothStatus();
</script>
```

To summarize - I want the data-boothon text and data-boothoff text to scroll horizontally across the page.
This is all the code I have access to.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how you keep track of boot status, so I will just use a `:hover` to switch between the two.

Because you have the texts as data-attributes, I can display those through pseudo-elements (before & after). I added `position: absolute`, `left: 0px` and `right: 0px` to make them take up it's `position: relative` parent's width.

I finally create an ongoing animation for both the pseudo-selectors that translates from -100% (out of bounce to the left) to 100% (out of bounce to the right).

```css
.btn-booth-container {
  --booth-container-height: 20px;
  
  cursor: pointer; 
  color: #F7F6F2; 
  background-color: #507C8F;
  height: var(--booth-container-height);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  
  /* ADDED */
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn-booth-container::before,
.btn-booth-container::after {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  top: calc(var(--booth-container-height) / 8);
  
  animation: my-move 10s linear infinite;
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-booth-container::before {
  content: attr(data-boothon);
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-booth-container:hover::before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-booth-container::after {
  opacity: 0;
  content: attr(data-boothoff);
}

.btn-booth-container:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes my-move {
  from  {transform: translateX(-100%)}
  to    {transform: translateX(100%);}
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-booth-container" 
      onclick="openIframe('https://www.websitehere/booth/XXXX//?embed=true')" 
      data-boothid="XXXX" 
      data-boothon="CLICK HERE TO CHAT WITH US IN OUR VIRTUAL BOOTH" 
      data-boothoff="SCHEDULE A VIRTUAL MEETING" 
      id="div_booth_status"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not 100% sure to understand the question. Here is what I understood you want to achived

```html
<!-- <script src="https://www.websitehere"></script> this line is commented for the demo only -->

<!-- It is not a good practice to add <style> tag inside the <body> but but it should work. It looks like you have no choice…  -->
<style>
  @keyframes scroll {
    0% {right: 100%}
    100% {right: 0}
  }
</style>
<div
  class="btn-booth-container"
  style="cursor: pointer; 
    color: #F7F6F2; 
    background-color: #507C8F;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 1em;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    position: relative;"
  onclick="openIframe('https://www.websitehere/booth/XXXX//?embed=true')">
  <div
    style="position: absolute;
      animation: scroll 4s linear infinite"
    data-boothid="XXXX"
    data-boothon="CLICK HERE TO CHAT WITH US IN OUR VIRTUAL BOOTH"
    data-boothoff="SCHEDULE A VIRTUAL MEETING"
    id="div_booth_status">DEMO</div>
</div>

<!-- <script>updateBoothStatus();</script> this line is commented for the demo only -->
```

Remove the word "DEMO" before you copy/paste the code, it was, well..., for the demo.

`animation: scroll 4s linear infinite` this is where you can change the [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation)